# ant build got failure due to "Unable to delete file xxx.jarSAVE"

Tags: ant, build, whitespace, manifest.mf

when i am doing ant build, every time build got failed due to Unable to delete file xxxx.jarSAVE. But this file is not there in that folder. i am attaching build trace here. Can any one help me for the same.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\2.4_BV_BuildArea\aiRES-Comp\Build.xml:162: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2.4_BV_BuildArea\aiRES-Comp\Java\Build.xml:225: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\2.4_BV_BuildArea\aiRES-Comp\Java\src\com\ibsplc\iRes\tax\build.xml:127: Unable to delete file D:\2.4_BV_BuildArea\aiRES-Comp\Java\src\com\ibsplc\iRes\tax\dist\iRes_Tax_ejb.jarSAVE
```

Answer (score 0):

ANT thinks that the name a file it it supposed to delete is `iRes_Tax_ejbSAVE`. But the actual name of the file which really exists and ANT is supposed to delete is `iRes_Tax_ejb.jar`

This means its a space issue. In some config or property file there is a whitespace between `iRes_Tax_ejb.jar` and `SAVE` is not being picked up.

search for the `<delete>` tag in all your `build.xmls` and you'll come to know which file is it picking the name `iRes_Tax_ejb.jar` to delete from.

Also search for the word `SAVE` in all your `build.xmls`

Then go and fix the space. This is tricky sometimes as when you see the text file, space might be visible, but ANT is not able to pick it up due to encoding issues. So you'll have to use the correct editor.

Comment: hi Pulak, thaks for reply. problem is ant is trying yo delete "iRes_Tax_ejb.jarSAVE". But with this name there is no file inside dist folder. But some times it's working fine. that time build was failed in some outher module with same issue

Comment: @user1605866 Please read what I have written. I have edited my answer so its clearer